# Non-similarity of possible Jordan forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Full exercise:
Determine all possible Jordan canonical forms (up to the ordering of the Jordan blocks) for a 6x6 matrix A, if A has eigenvalue 2 with algebraic multiplicity 6, and geometric multiplicity 3.
**Explain why the obtained Jordan canonical forms are not similar.**

I don't know how to show the fat printed part, can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $J_k(\lambda)$ denote the Jordan block of size $k$ associated with $\lambda$.  Let $\oplus$ denote the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum).  The possible Jordan forms (up to permutation) are
$$
A_1 = J_4(2) \oplus J_1(2) \oplus J_1(2)\\
A_2 = J_3(2) \oplus J_2(2) \oplus J_1(2)\\
A_3 = J_2(2) \oplus J_2(2) \oplus J_2(2)\\
$$
To show that these matrices are not similar, it suffices to find a property of one that applies to all similar matrices but fails to apply to the others.

For example: $(A_3 - 2I)^2 = 0$, and any matrix $A$ similar to $A_3$ would also satisfy $(A_3 - 2I)^2 = 0$.  However, $(A_2 - 2I)^2 \neq 0$.

Similarly, $(A_2 - 2I)^3 = 0 \neq (A_1 - 2I)^3$, so $A_1$ and $A_2$ aren't similar.